# NSString always passing NULL iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsstring, viewcontroller

I have a quiz.vc and i am passing an NSString from on vc to another and it passes null. (i am using a UITextView)

```
Quiz.h
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userText;

Quiz.m
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    // i have tried NSString *userText also and passing in userText to sfvc.string
    self.userText = self.textField.text;

            selectFriendsViewController *sfvc = [[selectFriendsViewController alloc] init];
            sfvc.string = self.userText;
}



selectFriendsViewController.h
@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSString *string;

selectFriendsViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", _string);
}
```

its always logging null at runtime? i have tried so many ways and methods!
any ideas as to how i can pass a string and not null???

Thanks

Comment: Did you "connect" the textField outlet in InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: yes i did i can see the connection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to show null,use the below code

```
  #pragma mark - check string is empty or not

   - (IBAction)next:(id)sender 
    {

        self.userText = self.textField.text;
        selectFriendsViewController *sfvc = [[selectFriendsViewController alloc] init];
        sfvc.string = [self checkEmpty:self.userText];
    }

  - (void)checkEmpty:(NSString *)check
   {
     @try 
     {
       if (check.length==0)
         check = @" ";
       if([check isEqual:[NSNull null]])
         check = @" ";
     }
     @catch (NSException *exception) 
     {
       check = @" ";
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error

```
  selectFriendsViewController *sfvc = [[selectFriendsViewController alloc] init];
  sfvc.string = self.userText;
```

This create a new instance of `selectFriendsViewController`,but you do not use it.It will be dealloced when the method is done.So,you got nothing.

If you fire a segue in the `IBAction`,use `prepareForSegue` to pass data.

**Edit,**
If you fire a segue when the button clicked.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[selectFriendsViewController class]]) {
    selectFriendsViewController * dvc = (selectFriendsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    dvc.string = self.textField.text;
}
}
```

Comment: i am new to ios development can you help me out please

Comment: Do you fire a segue in the method `next`?

Comment: i have not user the seque method to send the data before

Comment: thanks leo how can i put this method in the IBAction to pass it when i press the next button

Comment: What do you mean by "in the else condition"?

Comment: sorry i meant do i need to put the prepare for segue method into the IBAction

Comment: No,it is the method auto called by `ViewController` before fire a segue.

Comment: thank you very much your method worked, i have been running around and surfing the web for an answer but to no luck. you have helped me out so much. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think u can't navigate and push the value to next viewController 
use this code if you using xib files.

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    selectFriendsViewController *sfvc = [[selectFriendsViewController alloc] init];
    sfvc.string = self.textField.text;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:sfvc animated:YES];

}
```

hope that code helps you.